# Computing max t such that tanh(pi*sinh(t)/2) <1

Tags: c++, mathematics, boost, numerical-methods

I'm looking for a way to quickly determine that maximum value of `t` such that `tanh(pi/2 sinh(t))` is strictly less than 1, for a given precision.

I have reproduced the code I am currently using to do this below:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/next.hpp>
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

using std::tanh;
using std::sinh;
using std::asinh;
using std::atanh;
using std::isnormal;
using boost::math::float_prior;
using boost::math::constants::half_pi;
using boost::math::constants::two_div_pi;
using boost::multiprecision::float128;
using boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_50;
using boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_100;

template<class Real>
Real g(Real t)
{
    Real tmp = half_pi<Real>()*sinh(t);
    return tanh(tmp);
}

template<class Real>
Real g_inv(Real x)
{
    return asinh(two_div_pi<Real>()*atanh(x));
}

template<class Real>
Real find_max_t()
{
    Real x = float_prior((Real) 1);
    Real t_max = g_inv(x);
    while(!isnormal(t_max))
    {
        x = float_prior(x);
        t_max = g_inv(x);
    }
    // This occurs once on 100 digit arithmetic:
    while(!(g(t_max) < (Real) 1))
    {
        x = float_prior(x);
        t_max = g_inv(x);
    }
    return t_max;
}

template<class Real>
static void BM_max_t(benchmark::State& state)
{
    Real t_max;
    while(state.KeepRunning())
    {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(t_max = find_max_t<Real>());
    }
    std::cout << "t_max = " << t_max << std::endl;
}


BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, float);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, double);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, long double);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, float128);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, cpp_bin_float_50);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, cpp_bin_float_100);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

The build sequence is:

```
INC = -I/path/to/boost
all: perf.x

perf.x: perf.o
    g++ -o $@ $< -lbenchmark -pthread -lquadmath

perf.o: perf.cpp
    g++ --std=c++14 -fext-numeric-literals -Wfatal-errors -g -O3 $(INC) -c $< -o $@
```

This computes the correct value of `t_max` in 153 ns (`float`), 214 ns (`double`), 246 ns (`long double`),  5280 ns (`float128`), 53us (`cpp_bin_float_50`), and 455 us (`cpp_bin_float_100`).

How can this code be made faster? For reference, at double precision, I have found 30% of the time is spent calling `__expm1`, 24% calling `__ieee754_log_avx`, and 15% calling `__asinh`.

Comment: You do not handle `domain_error` and `overflow_error` (at least in this code). Can you assume they won't happen (or an undefined result is acceptable in those cases)? In general I'd not suggest this but you may well _re-write_ `float_prev()` removing all special cases (you already have a call to `isnormal()`...) and error handling you do not want to have. It's a tiny overhead but if you're really squeezing the ns...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any suggestions for making the code faster (other than pre-computing at compile-time, which I assume isn't an option for you), but I do have some general observations on the code style.

Instead of bringing definitions of the `std` and `boost` names at global scope, they can be isolated in the functions that use them (still with `using`, so ADL will continue to work the same as in the original code):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>

template<class Real>
Real g(Real t)
{
    using std::tanh;
    using std::sinh;
    using boost::math::constants::half_pi;
    Real tmp = half_pi<Real>()*sinh(t);
    return tanh(tmp);
}

template<class Real>
Real g_inv(Real x)
{
    using std::asinh;
    using std::atanh;
    using boost::math::constants::two_div_pi;
    return asinh(two_div_pi<Real>()*atanh(x));
}
```

Standard C++ provides `nexttoward()`, which can be used in place of `boost::math::float_prior`:

```
template<class Real>
Real find_max_t()
{
    using std::isnormal;
    using std::nexttoward;

    static const Real ONE{1};

    Real x = nexttoward(ONE, 0);
    Real t_max = g_inv(x);
    while (!isnormal(t_max))
    {
        x = float_prior(x);
        t_max = g_inv(x);
    }
    // This occurs once on 100 digit arithmetic:
    while (!(g(t_max) < ONE))
    {
        x = nexttoward(x, 0);
        t_max = g_inv(x);
    }
    return t_max;
}
```

Unfortunately, the Boost numeric types don't provide any `nexttoward()`, so you may be stuck using `boost::math::float_prior` after all.  :-(

The benchmark code can now be separable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

template<class Real>
static void BM_max_t(benchmark::State& state)
{
    Real t_max;
    while(state.KeepRunning())
    {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(t_max = find_max_t<Real>());
    }
    std::cout << "t_max = " << t_max << std::endl;
}


#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, float);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, double);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, long double);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, boost::multiprecision::float128);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_50);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_max_t, boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_100);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```